# Race condition on stack

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have simple class `Hello` and I am trying to call member function `say_hello` on different thread.  I created two different implementation it `hellos_in_stack` and `hellos_in_heap`. `hellos_in_heap` works as expected however `hellos_on_stack` have a race condition on member variable `_i`. How can I avoid it on stack using `mutex`?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mu;

class Hello
{
  int _i;
public:
  Hello()
  {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
      _i = 0;
  }
  ~Hello(){
  }
  void say_hello()
  {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mu);
      std::cout << "say_hello from thread " << ++_i << " " <<this << " " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  }
};

void hellos_in_stack()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        Hello h;
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&Hello::say_hello, &h));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }
}


void hellos_in_heap()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<Hello *> hellos;
    Hello *h = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        h = new Hello();
        hellos.push_back(h);
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&Hello::say_hello, h));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }

    for(auto hello : hellos){
        delete hello;
    }
}

int main()
{
    hellos_in_stack();
    hellos_in_heap();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's describe the race condition first...

The line `Hello h;` is constructing `h` on the main thread's stack. Once the `for` loop moves on to create the next thread, `h` is destroyed and another `Hello` is created -- likely, but not guaranteed, to be at the same address as the previous `h`.

`h` must be kept alive for the lifetime of the thread that is running its `say_hello` method.

One solution would be to create `h` on the new thread's stack. This can be done like so:

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    threads.emplace_back([]() {
        Hello h;
        h.say_hello();
    });
}
```

Another option, if you still need the instances of `h` to be accessible from the main thread, would be to store them in a container.

```
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
std::list<Hello> hellos;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    hellos.emplace_back();
    threads.emplace_back(&Hello::say_hello, &hellos.back());
}
```

Using a container we've introduced some more complexity. Now, care must be taken to make sure that we use the container itself in a safe way. In this case `std::list` is used instead of `std::vector` because calling `emplace_back`/`push_back` on `std::vector` can cause it to resize its buffer. This would destroy `Hello` instance out from under running threads!

---

Running example: https://ideone.com/F7STsf

Comment: Thanks Sean for the answer. So basically I always have to make sure the object used in thread is not destroyed before thread is finished.